# Can I save/resume game in Starfox 64?

Tags: starfox-64

I didn’t have a console growing up, but eventually bought a Nintendo 64 to enhance my childhood retroactively.

I just got Starfox 64, and have to admit I’m puzzled. I have beaten the first few planets / asteroid belt, but every time I turn on the game, I have to start over from the beginning!

What the heck? Is there no way to save a game after beating e.g. the asteroid belt and then pick it up a day later?

Note: I have a memory card, but don’t have a clue how to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope you can't.  http://forums.megagames.com/threads/saving-on-starfox-64.2177/

The game isn't very long you can beat it in one sitting if you wish

Comment: How long does it take to play through?

Comment: Off the top of my head an hour or two. I haven't played that game in years though but I remember it didn't take very long

Answer (score 3):

Star Fox 64 3D for Nintendo 3DS has been released since this question was asked. It's worth noting that you *can* suspend your game in Star Fox 64 3D. There is also a Score Attack mode that lets you replay individual stages.

As for the original Nintendo 64 version, you can't save the game until after completing it. This can usually take from 25 minutes to an hour depending on your skill level.